# Laurent Expansion of $\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

Find the Laurent expansion of

$$\frac{1}{z(z-1)}=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z}$$

in $0<|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$

I think I'm getting confused about which expansion corresponds to which domain. I've looked at a few examples, but have been unable to make a solid connection.

For the $|z|>1$, I think it makes sense to

$$-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}=-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{z^n}=-\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}$$

but further expanding this,

$$-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^3}\cdots=\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^3}+\cdots=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{z^n}$$

However this doesn't deal with the $z=0$ situation, so I know it won't work for $0<|z|<1$. I have a hard time distinguishing how to expand functions into the Laurent series.

Comment: It does not make sense to say "this doesn't deal with the =0 situation". You only have two cases: $0<|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$. Both annuli are centered at $z=0$.

Comment: In addition to what has been said, these are two separate questions. That's my hunch from your last paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laurent series for a given function can vary as one varies the annulus. Your exercise is such an example.

You have worked out the case when $|z|>1$ correctly.

In the case when $0<|z|<1$, you simply use
$$
\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\;,
$$
so that
$$
\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac1z=-\frac1z+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)z^n
$$

Comment: Okay, then my thought process was wrong about why my expansion for $|z|>1$ is what I wrote. For the $0<|z|<1$, why do we only consider the $\dfrac{1}{z-1}$ term? $\dfrac{1}{z}$ is just as important?

Comment: @help: $1/z$ is already a term in the Laurent expansion (at $z=0$). You may probably want to look at the definition of what a Laurent expansion at a point means.